# Android creating process which runs always

Tags: android

I am making an Android app. Every first day of the month I want to send a mail to a known mail address. The mail part works, but the first day of the month is an issue.

The app has to send the mail, regardless the app is running or is shown in recent apps. Also the app has to send the mail when the devices is asleep.

I have tried using a service. But this works only if the app is active and the device is not asleep.

I have also tried using the alarmmanager, but this works only when the app is in recent apps. And the mail will be sent when you unlock your device.

Do someone have a solution how I can solve my problems?

Answer (score -1):

Try using services for such kind of operation.Follow the link to understand more

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Which type of service do you advice?

Comment: Try to run normal service and use alarm manager to trigger operation at certain interval.

Comment: Alternatively you can also check Job scheduler.

Comment: I will try it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

look into a `Service` and `startForeground`. If you can let your Service die but get restarted, look into `onStartCommand` and `START_STICKY`.

Comment: Does this also works when the device is asleep and when the app is not in recent apps

Comment: It should but do read up the android documentation on it as well, especially, the lifecycle of service

Comment: I will try it. Thanks

Comment: Please accept any of the answers that help you once you find the solution or post the solution yourself if you find it. :)

Comment: If I have the solution I will post it here

Comment: That'll be really helpful